# How to display details of whats going on inside of a Windows Form with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

OK, 
So i've looked at alof of posts to try and figure out how to do this but i haven't got it.

all i want to do is display details of whats happening inside of a form. for instance, you know how when you install a program and it says:
copying blah blah blah.dll..
copying blah blah blah2.dll..
copying blah blah blah3.dll..
copying blah blah blah4.dll..
copying blah blah blah5.dll..
etc etc.
I want to display results of a query that i'm doing 
Am i making any sense?

Comment: Are you trying to update the contents of a form, while something is occuring, and you're not seeing the changes?

Comment: not really, please give more details... show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ? any errors ?

Comment: add a textbox and then any event you want to display is happening add a line textbox.text += "another event" or some such..

Comment: SOrry for taking so long to get back. Anyway, i think Prescott knows what i'm trying to do. whenever i have some code be executed i want thre result of the query to display inside the same window MUCH LIKE how a list of files being copied during an installation is shown.

Comment: I'd like to mark your comment as the answer @Prescott but it won't seem to let me. thats what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a textbox and then any event you want to display is happening add a line textbox.text += "another event" or some such..